# How to translate a file with Java

Tags: java, oop, internationalization

I have a file with these kind of lines:

```
UAFAviRefSinSubfamilia_cbAccion_0: Crear y usar la subfamilia de origen
UAFAviRefSinSubfamilia_cbAccion_1: Seleccionar mi propia subfamilia a usar
UAFAviRefSinSubfamilia_cxLabel2_Caption: Acción a realizar
```

I want to create an identical file, but with the content from the ':' until end of line translated to English.

Is there any kind of standard way to do this in Java?

Cheers

**-------------UPDATE:-------------**

As long as it looks like Google Translate API is not free now, does anybody know any free alternative?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the file line by line, search for the position of `:` and extract the string after it. Use this string as input to a translation service, like Google translator: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Comment: Do I have to pay for using it, right? Do you know any free alternative?